Getting a strange error while importing pycaret in Airflow
Getting this strange error while importing pycaret in a Airflow Kubernetes pod. This was working fine since deployment and there have been no changes in environment. Anyone know what this is about ?
Error occurs when running this line:
from pycaret.classification import predict_model, load_model
[
2024-11-05, 17:58:43 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/compat.py:36 FutureWarning: pandas.Int64Index is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.Index with the appropriate dtype instead.
[2024-11-05, 17:58:43 UTC] {best-action.py:154} INFO - scikit-learn version:1.1.3
[2024-11-05, 17:58:43 UTC] {best-action.py:155} INFO - XGBoost version:1.5.1
[2024-11-05, 17:58:43 UTC] {best-action.py:156} INFO - PyCaret version:3.0.0
[2024-11-05, 17:58:44 UTC] {font_manager.py:1423} INFO - Generating new fontManager, this may take some time...
[2024-11-05, 17:58:48 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1935} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 209, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/coder/de-main/airflow/eks-airflow-dags/holding/next_best_action/best-action.py", line 161, in get_predictions
    from pycaret.classification import predict_model, load_model
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/classification/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pycaret.classification.functional import (
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/classification/functional.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pycaret.classification.oop import ClassificationExperiment
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/classification/oop.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment.non_ts_supervised_experiment import (
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/non_ts_supervised_experiment.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment.supervised_experiment import (
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/supervised_experiment.py", line 53, in <module>
    from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment.tabular_experiment import _TabularExperiment
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/internal/pycaret_experiment/tabular_experiment.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pycaret.loggers
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/loggers/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .dagshub_logger import DagshubLogger
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/loggers/dagshub_logger.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pycaret.loggers.mlflow_logger import MlflowLogger
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/loggers/mlflow_logger.py", line 10, in <module>
    import mlflow
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from mlflow import projects  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import mlflow.projects.databricks
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/projects/databricks.py", line 12, in <module>
    from mlflow import tracking
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mlflow.tracking.client import MlflowClient
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 24, in <module>
    from mlflow.tracking._model_registry.client import ModelRegistryClient
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_model_registry/client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from mlflow.tracking._model_registry import utils, DEFAULT_AWAIT_MAX_SLEEP_SECONDS
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_model_registry/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mlflow.tracking._tracking_service.utils import (
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/utils.py", line 184, in <module>
    _tracking_store_registry.register_entrypoints()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/registry.py", line 52, in register_entrypoints
    for entrypoint in entrypoints.get_group_all(self.group_name):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/entrypoints.py", line 237, in get_group_all
    for config, distro in iter_files_distros(path=path):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/entrypoints.py", line 137, in iter_files_distros
    if folder.rstrip('/\\').endswith('.egg'):
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'rstrip'


please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. It's usually not necessary to use a version specific tag (like [python-3.8]) unless your question is really version specific, and the [python-3.x] tag is basically not necessary, Python  is Python 3, Python 2 has been sunsetted since January 2020
